# How do I get the buttons line up vertically with the text?

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I have this html:

```
<div id="details">
    In the meantime, 
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/iDreamStill" target="_blank"><img src="http://twitter-badges.s3.amazonaws.com/follow_me-c.png" alt="Follow iDreamStill on Twitter"/></a>
    or 
    <a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="DreamStill, a social music platform, is launching soon! Check it out!" data-count="none" data-via="iDreamStill" data-related="JustinMeltzer:Founder">Tweet</a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script> us.
</div>
```

The result is this:
[image]

How do I get the text and buttons all centered vertically?

Comment: Make the font bigger. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `vertical-align`:

```
#details img, #details iframe {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### UPDATE

Adjustments as the badges had some special markup. See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/8zcZf/

Comment: Wow, thanks for the down vote. See update, there was some special markup injected by the Tweet Counter. `vertical-align: middle;` is the proper way to do this for inline elements.

Comment: I actually didnt downvote you... someone else did. I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes

Answer (score 3):

`vertical-align: middle` applied to each image should fix the problem in most cases.

But if the buttons have shadows on one side or otherwise not exactly balanced, you might not get pixel-perfect alignment. In that case, use a little more brute force:

```
#details img { position: relative; top: -2px; }
```

Comment: Because this is not the way to do it ;)

Comment: @Thomas Correct me if I'm wrong, but this might be because you're applying it to the containing element. If you apply `vertical-align:middle` to the `<img>` tags themselves, this does work. I don't have IE6 on this machine, but have just verified in IE7+.

Comment: You're right. I've been misapplying it. I never really researched the standard since i mostly used table's valign. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas No problem. :) I have an edit awaiting peer review on the question that should clarify for others where the property should be targeted.